# How to solve the problem of PayPal gateway has rejected request?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am using Magento 1.9 and I have set up **PayPal express checkout as payment method** but I am getting an error like this:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Callback URL is wrong type; you
>   must use the HTTPS (#11813: Callback URL is wrong type).

So, can any one help me in this problem ?

Comment: Any help regard above error  @Manoj Deswal

Answer (score 3):

If you dont have an SSL certificate you can set "transfer shipping options" to NO and "Enable SSL verification" to NO then it should work ok.